# Question about meaning of "would" in this text

Tags: word-meaning

I read this paragraph and wonder what the word *'would'* means here.

> But distraught relatives gathered in a gymnasium on nearby Jindo island insisted more should be done, and vented their grief and frustration to anyone who **would** listen."Get my child out of that ship! Dead or alive," one distraught father repeatedly shouted to rescue and local government officials."

Answer (score 1):

*Would* here is *will* transposed into the past, as Maulik states.  Semantically, *will/would* indicates **willingness** here.  Here’s a straightforward example given by the American Heritage Dictionary under *will.*

> [Entry 3]  Used to indicate willingness:  *Will you help me with this package?*

To make this more obvious, we could paraphrase your sentence like this:

> They vented their grief and frustration to anyone *who was willing* to listen.
>
> They vented their grief and frustration to anyone *willing* to listen.

Answer (score 0):

The modal verb *[would](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/would?q=would)* is simple to understand there. The news is in past tense and *would* denotes the past tense of *will* there.

Go back (in past) when this would have actually happened. Replace *would* (which is a past tense of *will*) with *will* and It'll make it clear.

> *...and vent their grief and frustration to anyone who **will** listen (to them).*